# Volley How to order Requests

Tags: android, request, android-volley

i want to call 3 service methods (A B and C)  back to back. The important point is B must be called after response received from A and same situation between B and C as well. I add all of requests to queue using `RequestQueue.add(...)`. But now request B is called before receiving response from A. Is it possible to manage this using volley library.

I know i can do request B after receiving response from A but i want to know can volley does this work.

Comment: you need to queue request B after the responce from A is recieved.

Comment: i know that but i want automated logic for that using volley

Comment: there is a callback when responce recieved for each request. Use it...    
Volley does not have such a specific and easy implementation. It still leaves you abbility to write some code.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own Response listener so you can call A to B and B to C in the response callback method.

There is a simple example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17278867/508126

Volley can't do it itself but it can do it if you implement Response.Listener and add your logic in it

Answer (score 2):

You can't give request an order, but you can make them run one after another. For this you need to implement your own *RequestQueue*.

Here is sample which demonstrates how to make all your requests execute in the same order, in which you added them to queue, since it uses single thread execution.

```
// Copied from Volley.newRequestQueue(..); source code
File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "def_cahce_dir");

String userAgent = "volley/0";
try {
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
    userAgent = packageName + "/" + info.versionCode;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
}

if (stack == null) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        stack = new HurlStack();
    } else {
        // Prior to Gingerbread, HttpUrlConnection was unreliable.
        // See: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html
        stack = new HttpClientStack(AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(userAgent));
    }
}

int threadPoolSize = 1; // means only one request at a time
RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue(new DiskBasedCache(cacheDir), network, threadPoolSize);
queue.start();
```